# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'byte[]'

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

The image is meant to be added to an update sql statement to update the image id a user changes the picture. I am trying to call the `displayPhoto` method into the `savebtn` method and assign it to `residentImage` variable as the image placeholder.

**PhotoDisplay Method:**

```
private void DisplayPhoto(byte[] photo)
{
    if (!(photo == null))
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(photo, 0, photo.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        ResidentImage.Source = bitmapImage;

        ResidentProfileImage.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
    else
    {
        ResidentImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ResidentImage.jpg"));
    }
}
```

**Save Button Method:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Resident hello = new Resident();
    hello.Doctor = new Doctor();
    hello.Room = new Room();

    hello.addtionalInformation = txtAdditionalInformation.Text;
    hello.FirstName = txtForename.Text;
    hello.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
    hello.Title = txtTitle.Text;

    hello.ResidentID = GlobalVariables.SelectedResident.ResidentID;
    hello.Doctor.DoctorID = GlobalVariables.SelectedResident.Doctor.DoctorID;
    hello.Room.RoomID= GlobalVariables.SelectedResident.Room.RoomID;
    hello.Room.Name = txtRoomNo.Text;
    hello.Allergies = txtResidentAlergies.Text;

    hello.Photo = DisplayPhoto(hello.Photo);

    hello.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Text);

    ResidentData.Update(hello);
}
```

Comment: Please indicate on which line.

Comment: This is because you have something that is of type `void`, and assigning it to something that expects type `byte[]`

Comment: Please try to keep your code tidy, and easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

You have defined your `DisplayPhoto` function to be a 'void' function, meaning that it returns nothing.
Then how do you expect to get something back in `hello.Photo = DisplayPhoto(hello.Photo);`?

If you want to read something back from DisplayPhoto, probably you need to write something like this

```
public byte[] DisplayPhoto(byte[] photo)
{
      if (!(photo == null))
      {
          MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

          // .......

          return  stream.ToArray();
      }
      else
      {

          // Convert your existing ResidentImage.Source to a byte array and return it
      }
}
```

Comment: How do I go about returning something from DisplayPhoto?

Comment: @user2122032 You ***really*** should read about the basics. It will save you *a lot* of troubles and time. I'm not joking.

Comment: I cant return outside an if statement

Comment: @user2122032 You absolutely can

Comment: @user2122032 All code paths require a return value, so if you use `return` inside an `if`, you must also use `return` inside the `else` belonging to the `if` or outside the conditional. Alternatively, you can create a `byte[]` variable, assign whatever you need to it, then `return` it at the very end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set `hello.Photo` to the return value of `DisplayPhoto` yet it's return type is `void`, e.g. it returns *nothing* at all. Problematic line is here:

`hello.Photo = DisplayPhoto(hello.Photo);`

You need to make `DisplayPhoto` return a `byte[]`. Crude example: -

```
private byte[] DisplayPhoto(byte[] photo)
{
    if (!(photo == null))
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(photo, 0, photo.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        ResidentImage.Source = bitmapImage;

        ResidentProfileImage.Source = bitmapImage;

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        ResidentImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ResidentImage.jpg"));
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

Comment: @user2122032 Why not? What are you expecting, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Stills gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'